# Matlab Run Section not working

Tags: matlab, folding, code-folding

I encountered an annoying problem with Matlab 2016b: I cannot run folded code sections separately. More specifically, in Matlab editor buttons "Run and Advance" ans "Run Section" appear grey (unclickable) and Ctrl+Enter to run a code section does not work either.

My script **does recognize** folded code sections (separated with %%) just fine and I am able to use the "Advance" button to move between folded sections, so it seems the problem is not some syntax error hidden in the code. I am also able to run the script in the usual way with "Run" and even run selected lines of code with F9 command. I would, however, want to avoid using the latter option as "Run Section" and "Run and Advance" options are quite handy and do not require highlighting lines of code.

Any ideas what could cause the problem?

Comment: can you post a [mcve] that cause the problem?

Comment: Maybe a bad instalation

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies! Going through a small example did do the trick for me, see my answer. Rookie mistake, oh well you live and learn...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of the problem was my auxiliary functions defined within the main script. Since these functions were located in one of the sections, I couldn't call them from other sections separately. The solution was to save auxiliary functions as separate m-files. The following image highlights the problem:

[image]